# PHP chart diagram to display skipped entry

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to create a graph like this http://jsfiddle.net/9mmrbjt7/1/

I have a script created that will add the data to the graph. The date and the value is stored in db and it works just fine. 
The php script counts the number of dates and uses it as a value and assign it to the date.

The problem is if someone miss one day it skips the value which I understand.
So how can I assign value zero to skipped day?

```
2014-07-23
2014-07-23 = 2,

2014-07-24 -> wasn't submitted so the 0 should be added to the graph with the date.

2014-07-25
2014-07-25
2014-07-25= 3,
```

php script

```
$user_curr_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM rosary WHERE user_ids = $user_curr_id ORDER BY datum ASC"); 

$array1 = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ 
$array1[] = '"' . $row['datum'] . '"';
}

$tags = implode(', ', array_unique(array_map('trim',explode(',',implode(',',$array1))))); 

$sql =  mysqli_query($con,"SELECT datum, COUNT(datum) cnt
        FROM rosary 
        WHERE user_ids = $user_curr_id 
        GROUP BY datum;");

$result = array();

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                $result[] = $row['cnt'];             // add the content of field cnt
            }
```

in js script

```
labels : ["Start",<?php echo $tags; ?>] -> list the dates from db

data : [0,<?php echo implode(',', $result); ?>]-> list values from db
```

Comment: databases can't produce something out of nothing. you'd need a temp table that lists every day in your range that you could join against, so you can get a zero count for them, or you'd have to scan your data set in php after retrieving the query results and filling in missing days there.

Comment: yeah, I like to do the 2nd option but not sure how I can scan dates and if none assign 0

Comment: How about looping from $min_date to $max_date in PHP, if the a date is not set in your $result array, just add it with value of 0?

Comment: can you post example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php:

```
$sql =  mysqli_query($con,"SELECT datum, COUNT(datum) as cnt
        FROM rosary
        GROUP BY datum
        ORDER BY datum ASC;");

$result = array();

$start = null;
$end = null;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $result['"'.$row['datum'].'"'] = $row['cnt'];
    if(is_null($start))  $start =  $row['datum'];
    $end =  $row['datum'];    
}

$res_array = array();
if(!is_null($start)){
    $i = strtotime($start);
    while($i <= strtotime($end)){
        $res_array['"'.date('Y-m-d',$i).'"'] = 0;
        $i = strtotime("+1 day",$i);
    }
}

foreach($result as $date => $val){
    $res_array[$date] = $val;
}
```

in js script

```
labels : ["Start",<?php echo implode(',',array_keys($res_array)) ?>],
data : [0,<?php echo implode(',', array_values($res_array)); ?>],
```